# Custom jQuery Mobile Select menu

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm working on my first app in jQuery Mobile. I'm stuck on a select menu.

I've tried to copy/paste the "Your state" style at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/selects/custom.html and work it into my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CAST</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./global.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="home-page" class="type-interior" data-url="home-page">
        <div data-role="header" style="background:#AAA">
             <h1><a href="javascript:Load.main();"><img src="/logo.png" width="97" height="50" border="0" /></a></h1>

        </div>
        <h2 id="header_title"></h2>

        <div id="error" class="error" style="display:none;">Could not connect to the server. Please try again.</div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div class="content-primary" id="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="client" class="select">Client:</label>
                    <select name="client" id="client" data-native-menu="false">
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
             <h4>&copy; 2013</h4>

        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The select menu shows up, but it doesn't look like the custom mobile version on their site? It just looks like a regular select menu.

I don't understand enough jquery.mobile yet to really even know how to ask this question properly... but any help getting this to work would be appreciated!

Comment: it works normally here, as _custom menu_ should http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/mBuQU/

Comment: OK, I do see the html works like it should, all together... but why does it break when I load the menu from a jquery function? jsfiddle.net/w55ec

Comment: you mean like [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/GHUSp/)? 1) call enhancement `.selectmenu()` 2) you should load jquery before jquery mobile. 3) use `.append` or `.appendTo` in order not to remove contents of target element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the "Your state" example looks like a dialog, showing the contents of the menu alone in the screen, you have to add more options to the select element as it is stated in the page you link:

> When it has too many options to show on the device's screen, the framework will automatically create a new "page" populated with a standard listview for the options. This allows us to use the native scrolling included on the device for moving through a long list. The text inside the label is used as the title for this page.

I [modified the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mBuQU/1/) provided by Omar to add more options and it looks exactly like in the original site

```
<Ignore>Code so I can post link to jsfiddle</ignore>
```

Comment: OK, I do see the html works like it should, all together... but why does it break when I load the menu from a jquery function? jsfiddle.net/w55ec